# How can I select the first class name of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```
console.log($(this).attr('class'));
```

Which prints `className1 className2`. See? It's two class names. Because the clicked element has those two class names.

Now I want to get just the first class. in this case it is `className1`. How can I do that?

Parsing/exploding the result per *space* is a dirty solution. I'm looking for a standard approach.

Comment: Not very common to ever need to know the class name order. What is your use case?

Comment: @charlietfl My use case is something like this: `$("." + classname).position().top - 20;`

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `$(this)`? If relying on order matters seems like there is a better approach in general depending on what you are trying to do

Comment: @charlietfl I don't know. I didn't write the code. I'm just trying to develop it and I scare to change such a thing (I scare to break something else). I prefer to follow the previous programmer way.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] so we can see what you are doing. This all smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: There is no way except `split`

Comment: @Pedram I guess there is something named `classList`.

Comment: @MartinAJ `$("elment")[0].classList[0]` ? check this out on my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

### split()

First, get your class, then `split()` it by space and turn it into an `array`

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  var firstClass = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
  console.log(firstClass[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="className1 className2">Click me!</a>
```

### ClassList

Or you can use `classList`:

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  var firstClass = this.classList[0];
  console.log(firstClass);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="className1 className2">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: `$(this)[0]` is redundant use of `$()`. It returns same thing as `this`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var class = $(this).attr('class');
    var st = class.split(' ');
    var firstClass = st[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use classList, it returns a collection of all the classes the element
has

```
this.classList[0];
```

More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList